# fflush() sometimes blocks for over 1 second

Tags: file, server, centos, glibc, fflush

I'm using CentOs 6.4, and the kernel version is 2.6.32-358-el6.x86_64, with glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_46. Now a single fflush() call within my BIND9 dns server sometimes has to block for 0.4s to 1.2s, while that duration is usually within 10us. And that may happen about every 3 minutes averagely.

That makes the dns server periodically hangs. However, I cannot reproduce that on other machines. Maybe that is something about glibc or kernel, or something about the disk drive? Could anyone please tell me what's going on?

Any advice or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> something about the disk drive?

Probably.

1. You should look at `dmesg` output to see if the drive reports any problems.
2. You should look at `smartctl` output for it.
3. This has *nothing* to do with programming, and likely belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this is very much like what I encountered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607231/writing-data-into-file-fflush-takes-a-lot-of-time, but I'd Iike to know how to reproduce that on other machines. Any idea?